Given $\gamma=\gamma(t,s):I\times I\to M$ the vector fields $\frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial s},\frac{\partial \gamma}{\partial t}$ commute
The problem is pretty much stated in the title ($I$ is the interval $[0,1]$ and $M$ is a differentiable manifold). Clearly we can't use the fact that $\gamma_*[X,Y]=[\gamma_*X,\gamma_*Y]$, because $\gamma$ is not necessarily a local diffeomorphism. I'm aware that there is a question about the same problem, but I can't understand the answers. I'd like a complete proof (or a reference).

Presumably one of the $t$'s in the title should be an $s$?

Thank you for the correction :)

The content of the accepted answer to the linked question is essentially that the question you pose does not make sense. $\frac{\partial\gamma}{\partial t}$ and $\frac{\partial\gamma}{\partial s}$ are vector fields along $\gamma$, i.e. sections of $\gamma^*TM$, it does not make sense to take their Lie bracket since they aren't honest vector fields.

It looks like Deane's answer to the linked question gives the most thorough explanation. Perhaps you should edit your post to include the explicit details in what you are working on.

As @J.V.Gaiter points out, the title of your question is already incorrect. You'll need to rephrase your question rigorously. Perhaps it would help if you could provide a context where you need to use this.

Here's a way to think about this:
Given a vector field $X$ on $I\times I$, then for each $(s,t) \in I\times I$, the pushforward of $X$ by $\gamma$ is a tangent vector $$\gamma_*X \in T_{\gamma(s,t)}M.$$
This defines a map $$\gamma_*X: I\times I \rightarrow T_*M,$$ where $\gamma_*X(s,t) \in T_{\gamma(s,t)}M$. So this is not a vector field on either $I\times I$ or $M$. It's a hybrid thing. In particular, if you want to differentiate $\gamma_*X$, then you have to differentiate it with respect to a vector field on the domain $I\times I$.
If you let $X = a\partial_s + b\partial_t$, fix coordinates on $M$, and let $(\partial_1, \dots, \partial_n)$ be the basis of coordinate vector fields, then
\begin{align*} \gamma_*X(s,t) &= a(s,t)\partial_s\gamma^k(s,t)\partial_k + b(s,t)\partial_t\gamma^k(s,t)\partial_k\\
&= \alpha^k(s,t)\partial_k \in T_{\gamma(s,t)}M.
\end{align*}
You can differentiate this with respect to another vector field $Y$ on $I\times I$,
$$ Y\gamma_*X(s,t) = (Y\alpha^k)(s,t)\partial_k. $$
This, however, depends on the coordinates used on $M$. But if you calculate the "Lie bracket"
$$ (X\gamma_*Y - Y\gamma_*X) $$
in terms of $X = a\partial_s + b\partial_t$, $Y = c\partial_s + d\partial_t$, and the coordinates $(x^1, \dots, x^n)$, you find that $$\gamma_*[X,Y] = (X\gamma_*Y - Y\gamma_*X). $$
